# bootstrap carousel not working with flask routing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask

I have this HTML code in index.html:

```
{% block header %}
<header>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1900/1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>First Slide</h3>
          <p>This is a description for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1900/1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Second Slide</h3>
          <p>This is a description for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1900/1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Third Slide</h3>
          <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is my flask router:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The issue is, when I click to next button on carousel it won't work and the URL shown is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/index#carouselExampleIndicators
```

I know the problem is obvious, but I could not figure out the solution. I tried to keep index.html independent.. or tried to send carousel id back to router, and go from there.. but all of my attempts are useless. I use bootstrap 4.1.3 and flask 1.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the index.html page is missing a link to the bootstrap. You can get the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.js from [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) and save the css and js folders in flask template folder (where index.html is placed).

Adding `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">` after the `{% block header %}` and `<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` before `{% endblock %}` should enable the sliding of images in carousel to work correctly

Eg:

```
{% block header %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <header>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    .... YOUR HTML CODE FOR CAROUSEL GOES HERE ....
    </div>
  </header>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I am not sure why the block has to have bootstrap link if the link is already present in the base file from which this file was extended. Could you please tell me more about it?